# Understand the causes of the error message received in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, ftp, jobs

The developer who installed my Azure devops Git environment  left a few months ago. My new developer doesn't really understand this environment.
We were using it already for several weeks, but yesterday I received an error message:

[image]

If I understood what my ex developer said, is that he placed an Agent in me remote desktop connected to my server which I have to activate (run as administrator) in order to deploy the Azure devOps releases.
But this time there is a "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error which I don't understand an my new developer neither.

Comment: Did you google the error message?

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the issue, please follow the items below:

1. Set variable `system.debug` to `True` in your pipeline, and click the error in your screenshot to check the detailed error log.

[image]

2. Go to the FTP service connection you are using in your pipeline, update the username and password, or create a new service connection to make sure your FTP server is connected.

[image]

Comment: My developer is not sure how we give root folder from which it will copy files

Comment: Please can you tell me how I can add screenshots to this conversation?

Comment: You can edit the original post and notify me you have updates in the original post. Regarding the root folder, could you let us know which folder do you want to copy from?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: Now it works well. I was assisted by a developer who asked me to show him step by step what I was doing and this time it worked well